# Comparing changes in a value Ionic Angular (latest versions)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an app and there is a character counter and records to total counter. But there is a problem, I can't reduce the total counter number when the characters are deleted.

I tried to listen the backspace, but it wasn't accurate.

I am trying to understand how can I listen the character counter changes? If the counter counter goes down, this will be logged.

I know my code is not correct but I am stuck here.

```
showCount: number;

this.showCount=event.detail.value.length;

countDiff(){
        if (this.showCount === this.showCount - 1) {
            console.log("character is removed");
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you should listen to change event on ion-input tag.

Comment: On hrml element, set (ionChange)="valueDidChange($event)"

Comment: I already listening the ionChange but there is still a problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter and setter.

```
private _showCount: number;

set showCount(val: number): void {
  if (this._showCount === val - 1) {
    console.log("character is removed");
  }

  this._showCount = val;
}

get showCount(): number {
  return this._showCount;
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can use rxjs for async operations. I would prefer an async solution for perfomance.

```
showCount: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0)
  .pipe(
     distinctUntilChange(), // only do somthing if the value changes
     pairwise(), // give use the previous val and the new as array
     tab(([prev, new]) => console.log(prev > new ? `Decreased showCount by ${prev - new} ? `Increased showCount by ${new - prev}))
   );

// to update
showCount.next(event.detail.value.length);
```

I haven't tested any of these, but the code should be somehow correct.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now.